# Equivalence Relation Proof Question

Tags: equivalence-relations

Let $R$ be the relation on $N\times (N\setminus\{0\})$ defined by $((a, b),(c, d)) \in R$
if $ad = bc$. Prove that $R$ is an equivalence relation.

I'm pretty confused with this problem, mainly because I don't understand the significance of $(N\setminus\{0\})$. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: This happens to be the same equivalence relation used to say that two rational numbers are equal.  $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d}$ iff $ad=bc$.  Remember that a fraction $\frac{a}{b}$ cannot have $b=0$ (*though $a$ is allowed to be zero*).  If we were to try to define the equivalence relation on $\Bbb N\times \Bbb N$ instead, something fails.

Comment: The significance of $\Bbb N\setminus \{0\}$ is that $(a,b)$ is meant to represent the fraction $\frac{a}{b}\in \Bbb Q$. The resulting equivalence classes consist of fractions with the same value, but are simplified / expanded versions of one another (so $(3,4)$ is related to $(6,8)$). If we used $\Bbb N\times \Bbb N$, then every pair $(a,b)$ would be related to $(0,0)$, and transitivity would fail.

Comment: Trying to define the same relation on $\Bbb N\times N$ one has $(0,1)\simeq (0,0)$ and $(0,0)\simeq (1,0)$ however $(0,1)\not\simeq (1,0)$.  That is because $0\cdot 0 = 1\cdot 0$ as well as $0\cdot 0 = 0\cdot 1$ however $0\cdot 0\neq 1\cdot 1$.  Thus on $\Bbb N\times \Bbb N$ the relation is not transitive.  (*This is in analogy with how we say $\frac{0}{0}$ is an indeterminate form, it is able to be "equal" to anything*)

Comment: @Arthur does that mean that (c,d) is a fraction, as well?

Comment: Yes, it's the fraction $\frac cd$.

Comment: Part of the point of the exercise is to treat them as the objects they are, not just as the objects they resemble.  Use your definitions to show that $R$ is an equivalence relation, that is $R$ is reflexive (show that every pair $(a,b)$ is related to itself), that $R$ is symmetric (If $(a,b)$ is related to $(c,d)$, show that $(c,d)$ is related to $(a,b)$) and that $R$ is transitive (if $(a,b)$ is related to $(c,d)$ and $(c,d)$ is related to $(e,f)$ then show that $(a,b)$ is related to $(e,f)$)

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 things you need to show:

$x\equiv x$  (reflexivity)
i.e.
$(a,b)\equiv (a,b) \implies ab = ab$ which is true for all $(a,b)$

$x\equiv y \implies y\equiv x$ (symmetry) I am going to leave this and the next one to you.

$x\equiv y,y\equiv z  \implies x\equiv z$ (transitivity)

You can just grind through the algebra with little concern what the eqivalence relation actually implies.

However, it might help your intuition if you notice that:

$\frac ab = \frac cd \implies ad = bc$

And then it will make some more sense why $b,d$ cannot equal $0.$

Regardless, it is the same steps to prove the equivalence relation.